# How to map and opening ASP.NET solution file in TFS?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

What I"m trying to accomplish is to get the latest solution from TFS Team System Foundation, build and debug it. I can map the solution to my local folder but when I try to open it I have an issue where I can't build and debug it. Here are the steps I"m taking:

1. Open Visual Studio 2010; Open Team Explorer (using TFS2010) window; Open Source Control Explorer window
2. Navigate to solution directory example: $/WebSites/English/Development/Source/WebApp
3. Right Click Map to Local folder
4. Select folder; click yes to get files and wait for file to be moved to local folder
5. Open Windows Explorer, navigate to folder with sln file
6. Double Click sln file to open it

•   What I would like to occur is to have solution open; build and debug it

•   7. What occurs is another Get Progress that gets all files again and alters the file structure in Windows Explorer

Then when I attempt to run and debug the solution it doesn’t have all the files. For example in the browser when viewing the site a lot is missing, it’s not rendering correctly.

On a co-workers machine it works just fine.

Why doesn’t the sln file open correctly?

How can I open the solution to build and debug it?

Thank you in advance,

Catto

Comment: Have a you created a "Workspace" in TFS and mapped it to the server-local paths correctly?

Comment: Yes I have created a workspace. If I view the workspace the correct server is listed. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Ill assume you are doing a get latest version before you do this.

here are some things to check.

First expand the references for all the projects in the solution and make sure they are all correct, the icon will be different for anything missing.

Make sure the web settings are correct, they can be saved in the solution file or not, its an option.

Make sure there are no pre or post build events that are screwing things up

make sure someone didn't flat out forget to add the files to TFS or maybe they didn't check things in yet

if all that doesnt help make sure the versions of your referenced dlls are the same as your coworkers ... and the GAC if its being used